# jQuery Chosen plugin add options dynamically with out using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-chosen

first of all this is not a duplicate question. i checked all the available questions i didn't find the solution.

My Problem is, i am working in a project which is using `Jquery choosen` plug-in `version 1.5.1` to create multiple select form fields. in some `multi select fields` i need to add options dynamically if the option not available in the list. for example

i have a `tags` field with 3 options
1. male
2.female
3.kids but i am allowing user can able to add any new tag like `young` `baby` for this field. to achieve this  i did like this in following tutorial
[add attributes dynamically in using chosen plugin](https://boundlessjourney.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/adding-new-values-to-chosen-plugin/).

this is working fine. but the problem is this is adding new values in all `multi-select` fields. some fields like `products` should not allow to add. i have a very less fields to add dynamic values. so want to impliment that `case 13` logic in the form itself to add tags. till now i tried like this

```
$('#product_tags').on( "keypress", function (e) {

  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#product_tags').empty();
    $('#product_tags').append('<option>' + $(evt.target).val() + '</option>');
    $('#product_tags').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
});
```

its not working. how can i achieve this?? any help would be well appreciate.. thank you

Comment: The code looks find so I'd guess that your HTML is bad and you have more than one `select#product_tags`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".chosen-container").on('keyup',function(event) {
  if(event.which === 13) {
    $("#product_tags").append('<option value="' + $(event.target).val() + '" selected="selected">' + $(event.target).val() + '</option>');
    $("#product_tags").trigger('chosen:updated');
   }
```

});